Qt forcefully ends its execution with an exit code that is not 0. How do I get the error message?
I had a crash in my Qt application and I wanted to ask here. However, the error I am facing is very uninformative, as it occurs without an error message in the console from Python or Qt.
Although the question is general, I took the time to write an example code where you can see this type of failure:
import subprocess
import sys

with open("prueba.py", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write("\n".join((
        "from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget",
        "",
        "app = QApplication()",
        "",
        "widget = QWidget()",
        "widget.setParent(app)",
        "app.exec_()"
    )))


print(subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "prueba"]).returncode)

In which, I use subprocess in order to obtain the exit code (in this case 3221225477).
I tried:

Although I have not read all the documentation, I read the documentation for QCoreApplication, QObject and QThread on the PySide2.QtCore page (although the latter is a Python binding, it usually includes all the methods, virtual functions, etc.).

Search for Qt exit codes.

I came across this answer, but I wouldn't know how to apply it to Python or what it entails.


Therefore, how could I get the hypothetical error message?

The error code is 0xC0000005, Access Violation. It is possibly caused by the subprocess shell not having the path to the python executable. Try passing the full path rather than just the name python.

The exit code is Windows specific, I think. Maybe add Widows tag to the question. Then, what happens if you run the prueba.py script from command line?

Also, check out Pythons """ strings, so you can avoid using that join.

Note that QWidget.setParent() can only accept another QWidget instance (or None). QApplication is a QObject, and cannot be used for that.

@OldBoy It may be that I have been confused regarding the origin of the mentioned exit code. Although I think the command would work in the console, I will try what you indicate to give more accurate information.

@Hyde Regarding your first comment, I will respond to it along with the music lover's comment. And about the second, I got an IdentationError in test.py, and I don't really like having to put the string without indentation. But I'll see again if I can make it work like that.

@musicamante I am aware of the cause of this particular error. I think I phrased my real question wrong. Which is "How do I get the error message?" But thanks for your clarification!

@hyde I don't know much about the purpose of the exit code. However, I've edited the question to be clearer. In this case, the exit code could be a sample of how the "crash" works.

@DanteS. In that case, you don't generally get errors as you'd expect in Python. That error happens in the "C++ side" of the program, and when those happen there's little you can do. When a standard statically compiled program crashes, it's because some violation happened, which cannot normally be tracked down unless the program was built in debug mode and/or a debugger is running (which would still give cryptic results unless you know how those work). This is also valid for python bindings. Shortly put, if you expect to get something like a traceback for an error like the above, you can't.

@musicamante Thanks for the reply. If it seems appropriate to you, you can publish it as such and I will accept it. I hope they fix that problem in compiled languages.

@DanteS. There's absolutely nothing to "fix", that's how most compiled languages work; I won't go too far in explaining how those work, but a fully compiled program is a set of instructions that has no immediate relation to what "the code" does or how it's written: they have no way to tell "in what line" or "what function name" caused an error. The purpose of compiling is to translate humanly readable code into machine code which has no use (nor concept) of "lines" or "names". This is also one of the reasons for which such languages are normally faster.

@musicamante I'm interested in talking, but it's up to you to answer me. I don't know about low-level languages. Is it a binary structure, like the one seen in files? If so, wouldn't it be difficult to associate the structure with a name. Either way, anything that makes code incapable of allowing successful debugging is, to me, something to "improve" or "fix". What's more, I would study it myself if I had been able to install the c++ compiler and work my way through it.

@DanteS. With all due respect, your questions and objections demonstrate how little you know about low level aspects of computing. I never said that such languages are incapable of debugging: they are if built in debug mode and/or run along with a debugger. But doing this makes things going slower as compiler optimizations are disabled and extra checks are done at runtime, in order to do something similar to what you call "associate the structure with a name" (it's actually more complex than that); this results in a program that is tens or hundreds times slower than it could be, because it »

@DanteS. » has to do lots of extra stuff that is unrelated to its actual purpose. Even something as simple as debug logging can make a program quite slow. Consider all this like watching a movie you've never seen, while checking for all possible bloopers, even insignificant ones, without even knowing if there are. In order to be able to do that and actually follow the movie, you'll need to pay attention to lots of things, not just its plot, and you'll probably end up pausing/rewinding scenes or playing them again slower quite often: you are the debugger, you're slowing things down, and for »

@DanteS. » anybody else watching the movie too. When doing a release build you don't need all that, as, hopefully, all bugs have been fixed. Suppose that you managed to have a program that is bug free: would you release it in debug mode, making it extremely slower (or much more CPU demanding) than it could be for anybody, just because maybe there could be a bug that could be traced more easily? That would be pointless and quite wrong. So, there's nothing to "improve" or "fix". That's the purpose of debugging builds and debuggers, the finished program should never need such an overhead.

Does this answer your question? Debugging QT app in WinDbg

@musicamante I understand that I demonstrate this lack of knowledge, but it is better to clarify it than to give arguments pretending to know. As for the debug, I see, I misunderstood you. If it were possible and it would not cause anyone any discomfort, I would support launching a "debug mode" for qt, which could be activated or deactivated, if it does not have it and if it is a good idea. If that affects speed that much, then it is relevant.

"hopefully, all bugs have been fixed", in my example, I passed an app instead of a widget, an easy mistake to make in my opinion. Could it be a PySide bug? Why can't it detect those errors? I can no longer comment on that.

@relent95 Unfortunately, I can't comment on this, since I wouldn't know how to implement it in Python, but if you feel it answers it, I won't be opposed to voting this one as a duplicate.
